# How to align multiple content of a div to the bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a HTML code and Css code:

```
#header {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  <p>Header content (one or multiple lines)<p>
</div>
```

I would like the content of the header to be vertically aligned to the bottom of the header section, if only header is present it should be placed at the bottom of the div and if subtext comes it should aligned vertically to header and header should start moving upwards and as subtext increases it should wrap no overflow and it should move upwards direction:

So if there is only heading, it would be like:

```
--------------
|
|
|
|heading
----------------
```

if heading and some subtext , it would be like

```
|
|
|
|heading
|subtextsubtext
----------------
```

if heading and more subtext , it would be like

```
--------------
|
|heading
|subtextsubtext
|subtextsubtext
|subtextsubtext
----------------
```

How can this be done in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve that

```css
#header {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
 }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  <p>Header content (one or multiple lines)<p>
</div>
```